# Getting only first result from foreach loop, I need second result also

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
    $courseId=$e->courseId;
}

$getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId);
```

There are two result in $myassignment. I need 2 courseId from that but I am getting only one. How to get second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your assign code is out side of the loop

```
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
    $courseId=$e->courseId;
$getassign[]=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId);
}
```

Comment: `if($getassign->num_rows()==''){ print_r('no rows') } else { print_r('some rows') }` where should i put this inside foreach or outside

Comment: @Kevin outside foreach loop

Comment: its working but I want to do like this `foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
 $courseId=$e->courseId;
 $getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId);  
}                                                                                           
  if($getassign->num_rows()==''){ ?>
 <div class="price-course">
 <center><h3>There is no assignments available.</h3></center<br>
       </div>
 <?php }else{?>  <div class="price-course">
 <center><h3> assignments available.</h3></center><br> </div>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: $getassign->num_rows()=='' this line change to $myassignment->num_rows()==''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143982/discussion-between-kevin-and-bilal-ahmed).

Answer (score 2):

Store the values in an array like below:

```
$courseId = [];
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
    $courseId[] = $e->courseId;
}

$getassign1 = $this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId[0]);
$getassign2 = $this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId[1]);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
    $courseId[]=$e->courseId;
}

$getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId[0]);
$getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId[1]);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

$courseId can only hold one variable. You overwrite the first entry from $myassignment->result() with the second one.
Use an array instead:

```
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
    $courseId[]=$e->courseId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
    $courseId[]=$e->courseId;
}
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
$getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId[$i]);
}
```

using for loop (if you want in the future to increase the result you can do it by one change to this for loop)